# Laravel 5: validation error return values to fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I am creating a new entry and leave at least one field to error out then submit the form, upon validation the field values are blank.

Is there a way to return the values to their corresponding field when submitting? Something similar to CodeIgniter's `set_value()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On your form html, set the default value to

```
old('field_name')
```

Example if you are using laravel's blade:

```
<input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" value="{{ old('name') }}" id="name">
```

Example without blade:

```
<input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo old('name'); ?>" id="name">
```

You can also use:

```
Input::old('field_name')
```

Comment: This is not working.<?php old('name') ?> It gives null value

Comment: Try Input::old('field_name')

Comment: Not working :( <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" class="field size1" />

Comment: <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo Input::old('first_name'); ?>" class="field size1" />